Self Hosted Integration run time unable to find auth key using Azure.ResourceManager.DataFactory sdk Package
Unable to find any function to get the authentication key for SHIR
            `ArmClient armClient = new ArmClient(
                new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret,
                new TokenCredentialOptions
                {
                    AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
                }),
                subscriptionId,
                new ArmClientOptions { Environment = ArmEnvironment.AzurePublicCloud });

            ResourceIdentifier resourceIdentifier = SubscriptionResource.CreateResourceIdentifier(subscriptionId);

            SubscriptionResource subscriptionResource = armClient.GetSubscriptionResource(resourceIdentifier);
            var resourceGroupOperation = subscriptionResource.GetResourceGroups().Get(resourceGroupName);

            ResourceGroupResource resourceGroupResource = resourceGroupOperation.Value;

            DataFactoryData dataFactoryData = new DataFactoryData(AzureLocation.EastUS);

            var dataFactoryOperation = resourceGroupResource.GetDataFactories().CreateOrUpdate(WaitUntil.Completed, dataFactoryName, dataFactoryData);
            DataFactoryResource dataFactoryResource = dataFactoryOperation.Value;
            var dataFactoryIntegrationRuntimeData = new DataFactoryIntegrationRuntimeData(
                new SelfHostedIntegrationRuntime
                {
                    Description = "A self-hosted integration runtime from C# Azure SDK",
                });
            var createOrUpdateOperation = dataFactoryResource.GetDataFactoryIntegrationRuntimes().CreateOrUpdate(
                WaitUntil.Completed,
                integrationRuntimeName,
                dataFactoryIntegrationRuntimeData);
            Console.WriteLine(createOrUpdateOperation.WaitForCompletionResponse().Content);

what i am looking for is to get the keys
var keys = dataFactoryResource.GetDataFactoryIntegrationRuntime(integrationRuntimeName);
This is the python function for auth keys
auth_keys = adf_client.integration_runtimes.list_auth_keys(
        resource_group_name=rg_name,
        factory_name=df_name,
        integration_runtime_name=ir_name,
    )`



Self-Hosted Integration Runtime cannot find the auth key using the Azure.ResourceManager.DataFactory SDK package.

You can use the code below to obtain the auth key for Self-Hosted Integration Runtime using the Azure.ResourceManager.DataFactory SDK package.
Code:
var integrationRuntimeOperation = dataFactoryResource.GetDataFactoryIntegrationRuntime(integrationRuntimeName);
var integrationRuntimeResource = integrationRuntimeOperation.Value;
var authKeysOperation = integrationRuntimeResource.GetAuthKeys();
var authKeys = authKeysOperation.Value;
Console.WriteLine($"Auth key 1: {authKeys.AuthKey1}");
Console.WriteLine($"Auth key 2: {authKeys.AuthKey2}");

The code above retrieves the auth keys for Self-Hosted Integration Runtime.
Here is the full code to create and obtain the necessary process.
Code:
using Azure.Core;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.ResourceManager.DataFactory.Models;
using Azure.ResourceManager.DataFactory;
using Azure.ResourceManager.Resources;
using Azure.ResourceManager;
using Azure;

ArmClient armClient = new ArmClient(
                new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret,
                new TokenCredentialOptions
                {
                    AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
                }),
                subscriptionId,
                new ArmClientOptions { Environment = ArmEnvironment.AzurePublicCloud });

            ResourceIdentifier resourceIdentifier = SubscriptionResource.CreateResourceIdentifier(subscriptionId);

            SubscriptionResource subscriptionResource = armClient.GetSubscriptionResource(resourceIdentifier);
            var resourceGroupOperation = subscriptionResource.GetResourceGroups().Get(resourceGroupName);

            ResourceGroupResource resourceGroupResource = resourceGroupOperation.Value;

            DataFactoryData dataFactoryData = new DataFactoryData(AzureLocation.EastUS);

            var dataFactoryOperation = resourceGroupResource.GetDataFactories().CreateOrUpdate(WaitUntil.Completed, dataFactoryName, dataFactoryData);
            DataFactoryResource dataFactoryResource = dataFactoryOperation.Value;
            var dataFactoryIntegrationRuntimeData = new DataFactoryIntegrationRuntimeData(
                new SelfHostedIntegrationRuntime
                {
                    Description = "A self-hosted integration runtime from C# Azure SDK",
                });
            var createOrUpdateOperation = dataFactoryResource.GetDataFactoryIntegrationRuntimes().CreateOrUpdate(
                WaitUntil.Completed,
                integrationRuntimeName,
                dataFactoryIntegrationRuntimeData);
            Console.WriteLine(createOrUpdateOperation.WaitForCompletionResponse().Content);

var integrationRuntimeOperation = dataFactoryResource.GetDataFactoryIntegrationRuntime(integrationRuntimeName);
var integrationRuntimeResource = integrationRuntimeOperation.Value;
var authKeysOperation = integrationRuntimeResource.GetAuthKeys();
var authKeys = authKeysOperation.Value;
Console.WriteLine($"Auth key 1: {authKeys.AuthKey1}");
Console.WriteLine($"Auth key 2: {authKeys.AuthKey2}");

Output:
{
  "id": "/subscriptions/xxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxx/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/venkatdata326/integrationruntimes/myIntegrationRuntime",
  "name": "myIntegrationRuntime",
  "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/integrationruntimes",
  "properties": {
    "type": "SelfHosted",
    "description": "A self-hosted integration runtime from C# Azure SDK",
    "typeProperties": {}
  },
  "etag": "a900xxxxe0000"
}
Auth key 1: IR@07bxxxxf69-24c5711401b5@venkatdata326@ServiceEndpoint=venkatdata326.eastus.datafactory.azure.net@T0ekLxxxxx+Q=
Auth key 2: IR@07xxxxxxf69-24c5711401b5@venkatdata326@ServiceEndpoint=venkatdata326.eastus.datafactory.azure.net@RPNnqBy5xxxxxxbDNBdbKg=


Reference:
azure-sdk-for-net/sdk/datafactory/Azure.ResourceManager.DataFactory at Azure.ResourceManager.DataFactory_1.0.0-beta.3 · Azure/azure-sdk-for-net · GitHub
